# Elementary proof in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, logic, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilber space. Consider the following assertion:
$$(\forall y\in H,\langle x,y\rangle = 0)  \implies x=0.$$
We know that this is true. I want to check the following proof:
$$(\forall y\in H,\langle x,y\rangle = 0)  \overset{y=x}\implies \langle x,x\rangle=0 \overset{\text{positive  definiteness}}{\implies} x=0.$$
I don't know if the implications are correct. Thank you.

Comment: It is correct for sure.

Comment: What if I replace $\text{for all} y\in H$ by $y\in M$ where $M$ is a subspace containing $x$?. Does the statement holds because the same steps can be followed.

Comment: Yes, it would work the same.

Comment: yes because if it's orthogonal to $M$ it means that it's "orthogonal to itself", and then $x=0$